# Embedded Excel spreadsheets cross reference in Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

When you have 2 Excel spreadsheets embedded in a Word document, is it possible to one reference a cell value of the other one?

Comment: As far as I know, no. They are separate OLE objects and don't know about each other, or in fact that they're even embedded in a Word document in the first place.

Comment: @Randolph but is there any alternative? can I use a single spreadsheet and show parts/views of it in diferent sections of my word document?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, so perhaps your approach needs a review?

Comment: @Randolph I have multiple tables in my document. But when I change a value in the first one, this change should propagate through all tables that reference that value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this today in XL 2010 and I'm sure it's similar in earlier versions. Create two worksheet objects in Word.  Then right-click on each of them and choose Spreadsheet Object>Open.  With both open, link from one to the other, save them and close each.  The links then update within Word.

Comment: I've tried this, and while it appears to work, quite often the references are replaced with a "REF#" error. Is there some trick to this like naming the embeddings or something?

Comment: Unfortunately you can only open one Excel object at a time in Word 2013.

Comment: I've also tried this, and another limitation - when saving the Word document with a different name, the spreadsheet reference used continues to point to the source data in the original Word document. I imagine this also means the reference will likely run into issues when the file is moved to a different folder location.